# boost-bjam detect numpy include directory in JamRoot

Tags: c++, numpy, boost-python, bjam

I am writing a cross-platform boost-python and C++ binding. I have a project dependency with numpy. Is it possible to detect numpy include directory using Jamroot in a platform agnostic manner.

Please let me know if there are some examples for detecting include directories. Currently, on OSX:

```
<include>/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include
```

I would like to detect this automatically when I build the library on Linux.